# How do I resolve: 'google.appengine.tools.bulkloader.FileNotFoundError: data.sqlite: file not found' error?

Tags: sqlite, google-app-engine

I have been trying to fix this error: `data.sqlite: file not found` which I receive after downloading data from the datastore in Google App Engine. I have searched online for a solution but there isn't much information available.

I want to access the data I downloaded and upload it to local storage but I receive an error message. Thanks.

**Download Data:**

```
appcfg.py download_data  --url=https://foobar.com/_ah/remote_api/ --filename=data.sqlite
```

**Error Message:**

```
10:15 AM Uploading data records.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20160615.102315
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/appcfg.py", line 133, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/usr/local/bin/appcfg.py", line 129, in run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
    raise FileNotFoundError('%s: file not found' % filename)
google.appengine.tools.bulkloader.FileNotFoundError: data.sqlite: file not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bulkloader is being deprecated so the only option is to [backup and restore the data](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/datastore-backing-up-restoring) of application stored in the Google Cloud datastore.